# Two subnets using two internet subscriptions interchangeably

Tags: routing, subnet

We have two departments and two internet subscriptions (both adsl) at work.

We have two adsl router-modems (home type) that two dsl lines go into.

We want one department to use one internet subscription and the other department to use the other subscription.

But two computers from two different departments must be able to talk to each other over the lan at all times. We don't want to have to assign static IPs and gateway addresses on every single PC.

We want internet subscriptions to be interchangable so when needed we want to change which department uses which internet subscription. Even make them both use the same subscription when needed. And then switch it back easily to use separate connections.

What is the simplest setup to achieve this?

Comment: You need to get some business-grade routers, then it will be pretty easy. Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: This is quite easy to do, but how to configure it depends heavily on your network topology and on the router(s) used. Please add more details about this.

Comment: We have two td-w9970v3 wireless modem-routers. Topology now is basically two separate wifi modem-routers and two separate networks. The question is how it should be.

Comment: "_We have two td-w9970v3 wireless modem-routers._" Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You will need to be able to configure the routers for the fail-over and routing between the two networks, but we cannot help with that on consumer-grade routers. You could try to ask that on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Your quote is from a comment not from the question. JFL asked about it and I answered. In the end, maybe I will use a business-grade device with or without these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, with professional routers it is pretty easy.  It sounds like you want to keep much of the flexibility and simplicity of two links, so here are some thoughts if you're setting out along that road.

The following is imagining you have two small SOHO-type routers, for illustration Cisco 860-series or similar.

Consider two routers each with two ethernet interfaces and two ethernet switches:

```
      isp1                 isp2
       |                    |
      R1                   R2
     |.1|.2               |.1|.2
     |  |    10.0.2.0/24  |  |
     | =+====+===+===+====+= |
     |       |   |   |       |
     |       pc  pc  pc      |
      \                     /
       \                  /
        |   10.0.1.0/24   |
       =+====+===+===+====+= 
             |   |   |
             pc  pc  pc
```

It's exactly like two independent setups.  Each router is .1 and does DHCP in the ordinary way, and is default gateway for its network.  But it's also .2 on the other network, and doesn't give out DHCP there.  By dint of its interface route, it R1 will send 10.0.2.X to the right network; R2 vice versa.  To move a department or a PC you replug into the other switch.

In real life you'd do this with a VLAN-capable switch, but in addressing terms it would be identical to the above.

```
isp1   isp2
 |      |
 R1     R2
 |      |
=T======T=====a===a===b===b===
              |   |   |   |
              pc  pc  pc  pc ...
```

The routers are plugged in to trunk ports, having two virtual connections each.  The PCs are plugged into access ports, and the switch configured for sockets on VLAN a or b.  To move a PC you reconfigure its switch port.

There are a zillion ways to do this, this a just one.  Obviously you can get routers with more than one ADSL connection, but in my opinion (especially given where you're starting from), you're better off with two identical small machines.

This physical setup also has some other possible configurations: put in one VLAN, give routers single interfaces, R1 10.0.0.1/24, R2 10.0.0.2/24.  Give both non-overlapping DHCP (10.0.0.32-63, .64-95) each with itself as default gateway.  If routers are the same it's basically random which DHCP the PC gets (they'll tend to get the leasy busy router) and so you'll share.  If something goes wrong with an ISP or router, switch that router off, re-DHCP the PC (by reboot or wait) and it will connect to the other.

A third configuration would be to give static allocations in the DHCP to put the PCs into group A or B.

EDIT: a fourth configuration is three VLANs: a) dept 1 with R1 as 10.0.1.1, b) dept 2 with R2 as 10.0.2.1, and c) inter-router VLAN with R1 as 10.0.9.1 and R2 as 10.0.9.2.  You need a bit more routing on the routers, but it means that no PC could reconfigure itself to go out of a non-permitted router.

Hope that's helpful.  Whether any of this is suitable depends on your numbers and your risk tolerances of different factors.  How many people in your departments?

EDIT: With about 10 people, it's pretty easy.  I'd recommend the 2-VLAN method, configure a 24-port switch: 4 trunks, 10 VLAN a, 10 VLAN b.  Now you have nice simple configuration.  Put people in a or b by replugging: very easy to understand, takes seconds.  Be aware that a person could reconfigure their own PC to send out of the other one unless you take steps to prevent it.  Just to repeat: it's just a sketch for a starting point.

Comment: Like 5 people each.

Comment: You just provided some expensive expertise for no charge, you're a nice person.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you basically build two independent network and connect them with a router. This router becomes the default gateway for both networks and decides whether to route to the other side or towards the Internet routers.

A fast yet inexpensive choice for this central router would be a layer-3 switch. Given geographic proximity of both departments, you can even hook up all clients to this switch and use VLANs to separate the network logically.